# how to retrieve values based on a select option menu in Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

*let's say I have a cart system on my website and when an order is placed A user chose the type of delivery weather he wants his product delivered to his house or to post office and that value is different from a city to another.
well this is what my project is all about*

**1st I have a table on DB called 'delivery_fees'**

```
Schema::create('delivery_fees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('destination');
        $table->integer('domicile');
        $table->integer('stopdesk');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

- **destination** is the city or region or state.
- **domicile** is the house of the user
- **stopdesk** is the post office

**2nd my Select Dropdown list**

```
<select id="wilaya" wire:model="wil"
    class="hidden block w-full dropdown-toggle flex items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100
     bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300"
    onchange="closeFunction()">
    @foreach ($delivery_fees as $items)
    <option value="{{ $items->destination }}">{{ $items->destination }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**NB1**:`public $wil ='Blida'`,is a default value.

**NB2**:`$delivery_fees = DB::table('delivery_fees')->select('destination')->get()`this line retrieve all values from the table **delivery_fees**

**delivery_fees_table**:
[delivery_fees_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN8Ly.png)

**And Finally I have to radio button inputs inside form-elements.php**

```
<div class="flex items-center mb-4">
    <input checked id="default-radio-1" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="490" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
    <label for="default-radio-1" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
        à domicile: 490 DA</label>
</div>
<div class="flex items-center mb-4">
    <input id="default-radio-2" type="radio" wire:model="deliveryFees" value="315" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 text-purple-400 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-500-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
    <label for="default-radio-2" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Livraison
        StopDesk: 315 DA</label>
</div>
```

**Conclusion**
my objective is like this A user choses a **destination** for example state number 22 [destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAK7v.png) then those two value **domicile** & **stopdesk** are displayed on the radio button value
*In this case* **destination**= **Sidi Bel Abbes** **domicile** value =**890** and **stopdesk** value =**415**.

*I hope my question is clear, please feel free to add anything I might missed*

Comment: is there anyone who can help me ?